# Typescript modifying or extending call signatures

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Can one modify a function's call signature as follows:

given fn1:

```js
type fn1 = ( a: string, b: number, c: string )=>void
```

Psuedo code output required:

```js
type fn2 = ( ...fn1.parameters, d: number )=>void  // new type: ( a: string, b: number, c: string, d: number )=>void
//or
type fn2 = ( pick<fn1.parameters,'a','c'>, d: number )=>void // new type: ( a: string, c: string, d: number )=>void
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type utility [`Parameters<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to extract parameter information from a function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgRigXigCgIYC4oGdgBOAlnAOYA0UARjnAK4C2VEBlAxjvsWQJQoB8UAG4B7IgBMA3AFgAUHNCRYcAEwp0AOi1gMBDA1w4A2lo0AFXfojAWuADzwE-SvSYsAun2SDREyVAB6APQdPQMAfQAGTkISCihQ-VxwhFpGZlYEywiVGO54xIiAZjS3Ai8fMXEFcGh4IvU0U0LDKCNsKAsw61sHRH4jSPd2HC6rGwJ7RwGVYahxUozPAWEq-yD0Dq44kbxYskoFqFcMitWJOSA)

```ts
type Fn1 = (a: string, b: number, c: string) => void;

type Fn2 = (...params: [...Parameters<Fn1>, number]) => void; // (params_0: string, params_1: number, params_2: string, params_3: number) => void
type Fn3 = (...params: [a: Parameters<Fn1>[0], c: Parameters<Fn1>[2], d: number]) => void; // (a: string, c: string, d: number) => void
```